# BASIC Questions: Using ROUND for calculations

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, data-analysis

I am in Google's Data Analytics course and every now and then I get to a spot where I could just press on, but I want to know the answer anyway.

We are learning embedded calculations and a very simply equation was given:
`

```
SELECT  
  Date,
  Region,
  Total_Bags,
  Small_Bags,
  (Small_Bags / Total_Bags) * 100 AS Small_Bags_Percent
  

FROM `shaped-fx-370703.avocado_data.avocado_prices`

WHERE
  Total_Bags <> 0
```

`
[Resulting column from calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rq4pz.png)

I would like to know how to use ROUND so that the result in Small_Bags_Percent only go out to 1 decimel

I understand the syntax of round is `ROUND(integer,decimel places)` but I don't know how to point the "integer" to the results in Small_Bags_Percent.  I've tried THEN and even

````
 ROUND(((Small_Bags / Total_Bags) * 100 AS Small_Bags_Percent),2)
``` (hey, I'm just seeing what sticks lol)
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ROUND function goes round the calculation but not the alias for the calculation e.g.

```
ROUND((Small_Bags / Total_Bags) * 100,2) AS Small_Bags_Percent
```

Comment: I was so close. I should have figured the alias had nothing to do with the calculation so why include it with ROUND? Makes sense.  Thank you.